# Label with attribute "rel" doesn't make popup

Tags: html, file, input, label

why this code, when i click on label doesnt make file PopUp?

What is all requirement to make this code works?

Html code:

```
<label rel="photo">Load photo</label>
<input id="photo" type="file" name="photo">
```

Thanks for response

Comment: Try `for` instead of `rel`. `<label>` has no `rel` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 1):

Browsers doesn't use `Rel` attribute at all... Please read documentation:

[HTML a rel attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_a_rel.asp)

Also if you use `for` it will works. (as @Marc B suggested)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37jzmjws/)